# How to setup a host as a sendmail relay for particular IP subnet

Tags: sendmail

By default, sendmail (I have version 8.13 on an RHEL4) allows only local mails.

I wanted to allow mails from a particular network to be relayed via the system, so I did the following based on suggestions from various places :

1. /etc/mail/access : Added the subnet and the domain 
   8.37       RELAY
   mydomain.com RELAY (I assume this is the originating email's domain)

This alone did not work, so I added the following to sendmail.mc
FEATURE(access_db)dbl

Now, the problem is that it is allowing access from other domains as well. To test it out, I removed 8.37 RELAY from the access, and changed the email from field to abhinav@notmydomain.org

However, I still receive the mail.

What is the correct way to configure this, so that *only* mails from a particular subnet are relayed ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct syntax to allow a subnet to relay is:

```
Connect:192.168                 RELAY
```

How are you testing whether or not the server is disallowing relaying? Make sure that when you do your relay test, you're not trying to send mail *to* a domain hosted by the mail server. It'll accept it. Try using an external host to relay mail through your server to, say, gmail.

Comment: For IPv6 use something like: `Connect:IPv6:2001:0db8:85a3  RELAY`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "Connect:     RELAY" method in access, allowing relay from the subnet and rejecting the rest.